# How to infer the string literal in a nested object value by splitting a string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to build a required object parameter depending on which path you target in a object

```js
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
    [S];

type PropType<T, Path extends string> =
    string extends Path ? unknown :
    Path extends keyof T ? T[Path] :
    Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? K extends keyof T ? PropType<T[K], R> : unknown :
    unknown; 

type ParseMustaches_<T extends string> = 
  T extends `${infer U}{{${infer V}}}${infer W}` 
    ? Record<V, string> 
    : never

type ParseMustaches<T extends string[]> = ParseMustaches_<T[number]>;

type Prop<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K];

declare function translate<T extends { [L in K]: string }, K extends string>(obj: T, path: K, placeholders: ParseMustaches<Split<T[K], " ">>): void;

const obj = {
  "title": "Welcome to {{sitename}}, {{user}}",
  "button": {
    "text": "Click here to go to {{location}}",
    "num": 5
  }
} as const;

translate(obj, "title", { sitename: "", user: "" }) // works
translate(obj, "button.text", { }) // does not work
```

It seems to work for top level properties but nested properties fail, how could I fix this?
[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAeGUIA9gQHYBMBnKQ4AJ0VwHMAaKAEQ2zyJPMqoD4oBeAKCiC2FakxwFi6APzCOAbQC6UAFwCh6LONYBybVBmKVawRuYSoAAwAkAb0oAzCGSgAVAL636Hu7kfOAqm4W%20lByLnQAdFFwSKj%20dPScSqpCoTAKANx8fKCQUAAKZAD2YC7gECjhBQCGwAAWYizEpCJcvMayoppNNfUhAK64ANa4RQDuuEap%20bUN3eZDECBF9q4hLnIz9ckdW3NmrNY%20flAA0m4Rtg5OUABKQSGnjQtLK2syhSVlkJVypwp0W7cZRQQYjcaTFJCMGjCYZKDZXLQGZkQgQACy-VI1QAxnUIIQAPqVZ6sFocbg8BGCFyk4hHa4BNw2GxXXw3ABqbm5bJOAHUHh0ZLcIDiimR8CgOXRydRuB0QbgIAA3JyI8o1VEYrHAXH4wgk%20Zk9jURSUzVozHYvEE4kbXD9AC2ACMnApOFkchrPmBKnQnkbiItlqsXOaNv9PfhRfBqmRoPZBjjgIgipNyNVcIRYzhDQdiDZQgAZKCUM4KEGyqhQNz%20umdLgACiKzoAViCqmBZiDTnQELiIHUivBo6iQSjLTq9QS0AhkL9-nQAERQJecTgAShByqKiHwnrFWeAUBbrd4UBsaiXKeA8AgS5BS75EHgYsd0GARQvNkIyDw1Xfbk6BZLEnG5JcaCvZ1%20mAT9cAfC8OmvTQEKXABhJAcSGKB8XjKBPygKgvwIll4CKHFalTXBwMg1IlwdR0EIAVjUNw%20DcKBqmIQ9SE9DMsxzCBmzbZcbzvCCLxIP9cAAiBHwk0CyHkmsNxyMhM2zWohNPZdoNgtMIhwbAJMLNwNyAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the part where you said `T extends { [L in K]: string }`, since `K` here is not a key in general, but a path. So you need a little extra work to make your magic happen.

```
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
  string extends S ? string[] :
  S extends '' ? [] :
  S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
  [S];

type PropType<T, Path extends string> =
  string extends Path ? unknown :
  Path extends keyof T ? T[Path] :
  Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? K extends keyof T ? PropType<T[K], R> : unknown :
  unknown;

type ParseMustaches_<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer U}{{${infer V}}}${infer W}`
  ? Record<V, string>
  : never

type ParseMustaches<T extends string[]> = ParseMustaches_<T[number]>;

// You need to this utility type
type TypeOnPath<Path extends string, T> =
  string extends Path ? unknown :
  Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? { [k in K]: TypeOnPath<R, T> } :
  { [k in Path]: T };

declare function translate<K extends string, T extends TypeOnPath<K, string>>
  (obj: T, path: K, placeholders: ParseMustaches<Split<PropType<T, K> & string, " ">>): void;

const obj = {
  "title": "Welcome to {{sitename}}, {{user}}",
  "button": {
    "text": "Click here to go to {{location}}",
    "num": 5
  }
} as const;

translate(obj, "title", { sitename: "", user: "" })
translate(obj, "button.text", {}) // now we have an error saying that 'location' is missing
translate(obj, "button.num", {}) // correctly report error saying 'button.num' is not a string
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=95#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAeGUIA9gQHYBMBnKQ4AJ0VwHMAaKAEQ2zyJPMqoD4oBeAKChsK1JjgLF0AfiEcA2gF0oALgGxRLYgHJNUaQuWr0WMawAGAEgDelAGYQyUACoBfK-VfXcdhwFVnp3ShZRzoAOnC4JFQfOnpORRVBWRh5AG4+PlBIKAAFMgB7MEdwCBQQ3IBDYAALdXEZam5+QVJhKjrWHKra6QBXXABrXHyAd1wDQS6ajuIBiBB8mydAx1kp6oTVdZmoC09vKABpZ1CrW3soACV-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)

## Update

To get the desired behavior mentioned in the comment, you can modify `Split`:

```
// Remove constraint on S so that it takes any input type
type Split<S, D extends string> =
  S extends string ? (
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
    [S]
  ) : never;

type PropType<T, Path extends string> =
  string extends Path ? unknown :
  Path extends keyof T ? T[Path] :
  Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? K extends keyof T ? PropType<T[K], R> : unknown :
  unknown;

type ParseMustaches_<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer U}{{${infer V}}}${infer W}`
  ? Record<V, string>
  : never

type ParseMustaches<T extends string[]> = ParseMustaches_<T[number]>;

type TypeOnPath<Path extends string, T> =
  string extends Path ? unknown :
  Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? { [k in K]: TypeOnPath<R, T> } :
  { [k in Path]: T };

// This time we use TypeOnPath<K, any>
declare function translate<K extends string, T extends TypeOnPath<K, any>>
  (obj: T, path: K, placeholders: ParseMustaches<Split<PropType<T, K>, " ">>): void;

const obj = {
  "title": "Welcome to {{sitename}}, {{user}}",
  "button": {
    "text": "Click here to go to {{location}}",
    "num": 5
  }
} as const;

translate(obj, "title", { sitename: "", user: "" })
translate(obj, "button.text", {}) // now we have an error saying that 'location' is missing
translate(obj, "button.num", {}) // error with never
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88#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)

Comment: Thank you! but that last error is not wanted behaviour, the path can resolve to any value in the object, it's fine if it's a number or string or array

Comment: But how are you supposed to parse the value then? Your `ParseMustaches_` only accepts string.

Comment: If the value resolves to something that's not a string, the 3rd param should be never, just like when there are no mustache notations